# What are the different types of XML sitemaps that can be submitted to search engines?

Tags: seo, sitemap

I recently came to know about [Image sitemaps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?hl=en). Can someone list **ALL** possible types of sitemaps currently used for listing entire website to search engines?

Comment: Sitemaps do not positively effect search performance at all short of being able to list pages that cannot be accessed during a crawl. Do not think that adding a sitemap will make your site perform better in search. SEOs like to parrot false information on the subject.

Comment: Sitemaps are important for large database driven websites, especially ones where users find the content primarily through search and the website may not have static links to all pages.  Sitemaps certainly have limitations for SEO.  Just because a page is listed in the sitemap doesn't mean that it can rank for anything, especially anything competitive.   See [The Sitemap Paradox](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox) for lots more information.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller This is crazy. I always trusted sitemaps to help list my websites to search engines. Thanks lot of tons bro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has a [help document about sitemaps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en) in which they list the various types:

- [web](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en)
- [video](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80471)
- [image](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636)
- [mobile](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34627)
- [news](https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/74288)